How to enable macOS text shortcuts to the current terminal command?
I would like to know if there is a way to enable macOS keyboard shortcuts for editing text to work for the command I'm currently writing.
For example, I would like:

Command+← moves the cursor to the beginning of the line.
Command+→ moves the cursor to the end of the line.
Command+Delete removes text from the beginning of the line to the current cursor.
Option+←/→ moves the cursor to the edge of the previous or next word.
Option+Delete deletes the last word until the cursor.

Is there any way to achieve that?

Found an answer using iTerm2. According to this and this the following can be achieved in iTerm2
Go to iTerm2>Settings>Profiles>Keys>Key Mappings and from the preset dropdown on the bottom select Natural Text Editing: 
The key bindings will be shown above

Run cat in Terminal.
Then press ⌘ + ←.
The escape sequence corresponding to ⌘ + ← will be printed to the screen. I don't have a Mac, but, for example, on Gnome Terminal / Ubuntu pressing Ctrl + ← would output:
^[[1;5D

Then bind the escape sequence to the corresponding action (in this case backward-word):
bindkey '<sequence>' backward-word 

replacing <sequence> with the output of cat.
Then rinse and repeat for all the sequences you want to map.
The actions you want to map are, in order:

beginning-of-line
end-of-line
backward-kill-line
backward-word
forward-word
backward-kill-word

I suggest you put all your bindkey commands (as you're figuring them out) in ~/.zshrc instead of running them, so that they'll be run each time ~/.zshrc is sourced (i.e. every time you spawn a shell / open a new Terminal instance).
Finally, run . ~/.zshrc.

@user2565010 If you’d care to post your bindkey commands somewhere (like Pastebin), I’d be happy to incorporate them into the answer. This way, those looking for those exact escape sequences won’t have to use cat / search beyond this answer to find them.

This is an amazing approach, but it has a problem for mac in particular: if using zsh, the cat command exits immediately. If using bash or sh, the cat command works as expected except when trying cmd hotkeys. Nothing happens if I press cmd + left for example.

@user2565010 Right, try this: instead of Command + whatever, try Ctrl + whatever; then replace the initial ^ with \e, and that should be your sequence. I'm not sure why cat would exit immediately in Zsh, I can use cat that way in both Zsh and Bash without issues

So the Control key doesn't register any keys in cat (or sed -n l) but Option does. So bindkey '^[^[[D' beginning-of-line does make Option+left go to the beginning of line. However, replacing the first ^[ characters with \e has the exact same effect. cmd key seems to simply not be registered.

The answer is still amazing, but I think there's a deeper issue with the terminal (or iterm2 - seems to be similarly neutered). There are some keyboard settings under the terminal profile (that don't accept cmd) and iterm2 has some keyboard shortcuts, but it's not obvious they support current command actions

I can kind of understand why Control and cmd keys might not be captured by the terminal - they wanted to preserve OSX window controls, such as changing desktops (ctrl+right) or tab management (cmd+t). But cmd+left/cmd+delete are deliberately unbound so that they can be used for text input. Wondering why we can't change those easily

@user2565010 ^[ should map to Cmd, and \e to Option according to this (I mixed them up in my previous comment, sorry about that), is this not the case? Which macOS / Terminal version? I might try and spin up a macOS VM later to try this out (if I can find the ISO / VirtualBox doesn't complain too much, I'll take it as an excuse to finally set one up)

@user2565010 Anyway Ctrl alone wouldn't show up in cat's output, I don't know what you tried but bear in mind it should be entered along with another key at least
